# Runaway argument with linguex

Tags: errors, linguex

Compiling some `linguex` code gives me:

```
Runaway argument?
\newgll  [CP Ceapann tú [CP go bhuailfidh an píobaire an t-amhrán \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \ai.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex. \aig. [CP Ceapann tú [CP go bhuailfidh an píobaire an t-amhrán ]] \\
          think you that play.FUT the piper the song\\
          `You think that the piper will play the song.'\\
 \big. An t-ór seo$_i$ [CP a$_N$ chreid corr-dhuine [CP go raibh sé$_i$ ann ] ].\\
       the gold DEM that.RSMP thought some-people that was it there\\
       `This gold that some people thought was there'\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an empty line after every `\ex.`. The following works fine (apart from an underfull `\hbox`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex. \aig. [CP Ceapann tú [CP go bhuailfidh an píobaire an t-amhrán ]] \\
          think you that play.FUT the piper the song\\
          `You think that the piper will play the song.'\\

\end{document}
```

Page 1 of the [`linguex` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/linguex):

> The list environment created by `\ex.` must be closed by a single blank line
>   (a `\par`). The text following this list will not be indented. In order to get a
>   `\parindent`, a *second* blank line must be added, immediately following the first.

Comment: What about multiple lines?  http://sprunge.us/JUGA gives me the same error.

Comment: @Tass That doesn't give me any errors, just the same warning. Deleting the auxiliary files might help? Generally: Please always include all code, output, etc. directly here on the site, i.e. edit your question if new "evidence" comes up, and point to that in the comments.

Comment: I get  http://sprunge.us/aCcK

Comment: @Tass Please edit your question if you have more data to show.

Comment: Well, I basically get the same error.